# where in memory are this variables stored on c?

Tags: c, memory-management, ram, rom

If I have code like this:

```
const int a=2;
int b;
int main()
{
const int c=4
static int d;
int e;
int f=5;
}
```

Where in memory (stack, data, heap) are these variables stored(especially the local undefined variable e) ?
undefined local variable e will have a garbage value ( where did it come from?)

Comment: Platform/OS/... depends. Why worry

Comment: Who said they'll even be stored anywhere?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address

Comment: My compiler refuses this ("error: unknown type name 'constant'") but even if it did, it's smart enough to see that none of these values are used. Dead code elimination ensues, and nothing is stored in memory.

Comment: Where in memory (stack, data, heap) are these variables stored(especially the local undefined variable e) ? undefined local variable e will have a garbage value ( where did it come from?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- global variables -------> data
- static variables -------> data
- constant data types -----> code and/or data. Consider string literals for a situation when a constant itself would be stored in the data segment, and references to it would be embedded in the code
- local variables(declared and defined in functions) --------> stack
- variables declared and defined in `main` function ----->  stack
- pointers(ex: `char *arr`, `int *arr`) -------> data or stack, depending on the context. C lets you declare a global or a `static` pointer, in which case the pointer itself would end up in the data segment.
- dynamically allocated space(using `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`) -------->  heap

It is worth mentioning that "stack" is officially called "automatic storage class".

Comment: what about the undefined local variable e?

Comment: variables declared and defined in main function -----> stack

Comment: variables declared only?

Comment: Once you declare a variable with data type, it'll be saved in stack.